# WPF app cant load image and related info into second form

Tags: wpf

Hey everyone i need help with a WPF app im writing.

it consists of 2 forms a main input window and a script(pharmacy script app) window

on the main input window it has a combobox with 2 items : clicks and dischem, depending on what is chosen there it needs to load the logo of that pharmacy into the script window.

at the top of the script window it has an image control

how can i accomplish this?

Comment: What have you done so far? How the windows are created (At the same time or does the 2nd one created on the selection event)?

Comment: on the main page there is a button that when clicked it goes to the next window and is supposed to load the image and addresses of the selected pharmacy

Comment: i have the two pages created with the mentioned button and combobox on the mainwindow.xaml and on the second page i have a image control for the logo and a label that updates with the address of the pharmacy

Comment: If I understood correctly you have something like - button_click -> new window2().Show(); If so, why don't you add a constructor that has an Image control in so you can do new window2(SelectedImage).Show();

Comment: yes that is correct, in the window2(SelectedImage) would i put the image that i selected in the combobox inside the brackets? lets say its clicks.jpg how would i link that in the brackets? the combobox name is PharmacyComboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (PharmacyComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
        new Window2(PharmacyComboBox.SelectedItem as Image).Show();
}
```